# Anyone know what program the Apple store demos likely use to make their interactive desktop

Tags: cocoa, quartz-graphics

I have a project that I am attempting to do and we want something similar to what the Apple store does. We thought it was a Quartz Composer interactive desktop but I've been putting together an xcode cocoa solution to do it too.

Here is an image of what I'm wondering about it is just a Title and 3 images that link out to url locations. If anyone can point me in the direction they believe can make something like this I would appreciate it.

I have used Quartz Desktop to display a .qtz but it isn't interactive. If anyone knows of another quartz desktop displaying .app that does use the interactive parts such as mouse and keyboard, it would be appreciated.

[Applestore demo http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/614/dsc03934y.jpg](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/614/dsc03934y.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a custom proprietary program called, if I remember correctly, Concierge. But it's not doing anything tricky. You can make any NSWindow appear on the desktop by setting its window level to kCGDesktopWindowLevel.

Comment: Thanks I've been working over solutions all day. Figured I would see what everyone else knew about it.

Comment: I had a coworker do some research at the apple store, The program running this is called DesktopButtons, but it is tied in to Concierge services from what I read. Its actually not to hard to make a program that looks like this one.